# Cannot add user certificates for EAP-TLS on Android 13

Tags: wi-fi, android-13

I want to connect to a WPA2 Enterprise wifi network.
I have three keys/certs to install: `ca.pem`, `client.crt`, `client.key`.

I have manage to install the `ca.pem` certificate in my phone and the `client.crt`.

In my wifi settings, I select my network, then the eap method (TLS) then the ca certificate but I cannot select the user certificate.

How can I select the user certificate in the wifi settings for my network.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot select the user certificate"? Is the user certificate field missing or is the field present but your certificate is missing in the list? How has you installed the client certificate and key?

Comment: @Robert I can't select a my client certificats as it is not in the list as there is no list. The "user certificats" part is grey. I can't even change something in it

Comment: Same here - After selecting "EAP method" "TLS" and selecting "CA certificate" "Do not validate" I can't change "User certificate" from "Do not provide". So I can't connect to the network in the same way I do on a desktop.